# Where can I find the reputation black market?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation

Apparently there is one around, at least I can't explain the recent jump in reputation of 4k for [user 1026](https://stackapps.com/users/1026) by any other means (just kidding of course, no offense please ;)

The `API Beta` badge accounts for +2k rep but the `API Evangelist` one is absent, so the +4k rep in place now (additional even, it used to be either/or for these two API related badges) don't seem to have an obvious source, or am I missing something here?

I realized this yesterday already while toying around with code poets recent creation [SOAPI.FindUser](https://stackapps.com/questions/1338/soapi-finduser-quickly-find-a-any-stack-exchange-user) and thought it might be a temporary glitch to vanish soon, but since it is still around while toying around with code poets even more recent creation [SOAPI.FindUser (Silverlight Edition)](https://stackapps.com/questions/1344/soapi-finduser-silverlight-quickly-find-any-user-anywhere-in-the-stackiverse) I thought I might as well ask for the dirty secrets in public for a change ;)

Yesterday Googles cache still didn't feature the current 6k reputation, but today it has been updated and accordingly this is in place since 8 Aug 2010 07:26:40 GMT at least.

Comment: I noticed this a few days ago.  Something is definitely fishy with that account.

Comment: A Google Wave app is fishy http://stackapps.com/questions/1286/robostack-a-google-wave-robot-for-stackexchange-api .

Comment: weird how that guy made announced a wave app on like the same day as wave was announced dead and has now jumped up 4k.

Comment: yeah. unless there is something that we don't know about (which there most probably is) dude is cutting the line without contributing to the community. What's up with that? (ooooeeeee, wuwt, wuwt!?)

Comment: @code: I'm trying to think of what significance 1026 has... but I can't think of anything.

Comment: as per kevin's answers - i guess the question should be 'Where can I find the Bonus Badge Black Market?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That account ended up with 3x API Beta badges (behind the scenes, only one displayed).  Two of them have been removed.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing fishy. I think there is a bug with StackApps reputation system. Or perhaps a hidden feature that I myself do not know. I definitely have merged accounts from 3-4 other sites recently. But that shouldn't be a problem, is it?
FYI The API Beta badge is not bogus. And it surely has nothing to do with the Google Wave APP.
So much for conspiracy theories :).

Comment: +1 for stepping in to resolve the mystery around yourself (there goes the repro scenario ;) - I'm pretty sure that nobody really thought there would be something fishy, I certainly didn't, rather people apparently enjoy having some fun while speculating about weird things witnessed in the context of the Stack Exchange engine, aka bugs or 'hidden features' indeed :) Your welcome participation can take the guess work out of this exploration: So you did indeed join Stack Apps during the Private Beta already, but haven't gotten any upvote on a post to warrant the `API Evangelist` badge too?

Comment: @Steffen No. I haven't got the API Evangelist badge.

Comment: And with *merged accounts from 3-4 other sites recently* you probably meant that you **associated** your accounts from other Stack Exchange sites with the one here? Because *merging* as linked via [@systempuntoouts answer](http://stackapps.com/questions/1346/where-can-i-find-the-reputation-black-market/1360#1360) usually means merging several accounts from a single person on a single site (possibly from registering twice accidentally for example) into one account only. If so, did you by chance associate accounts on Aug 8? Shouldn't be a problem, of course, but might have triggered a bug here.

Comment: Yes. Probably on August 8, Sunday.

Answer (score 1):

I totally believe you. I had a similar question on Meta once when I had *another* issue with this user's reputation... *but the question was mysteriously deleted!*

It really baffles me...

Answer (score 1):

There could be another explanation:

[User accounts can be merged.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-stack-overflow-accounts-users-anon)

Comment: Good point, but shouldn't this show up in the activity/timeline then accordingly, i.e. include respective posts/tags/badges?

Comment: @Steffen Ask to him :), he has answered!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, yes, very fishy indeed...

Let's see here:

- 2000 - API beta
- 2050 - 10 upvotes on questions = +50
- 2050 - 0 accept-answer-on-your-own-question bonuses = +0
- 2070 - 2 upvotes on answers = +20
- 2070 - 0 accepted answers = +0

So the user goes from 2070 to 6137 inexplicably...

I say that **either there's a massive bug or the user contributed in some questions that have now been deleted**.

Then again, >4k rep from deleted contributions on Stack Apps in a single day? Sure, 4k from deleted content is very high anyway, but there's **no way to get more that 200 rep in a single day**.

Someone with the ability to see deleted content - please take a look. However, I doubt that this is the real issue here.

Comment: Actually the user received 11 upvotes on questions and 3 upvotes on answers with 1 downvote each (the stats tab doesn't provide the complete picture, use the API instead ;) This yields 137 exactly if you factor in the 1 point everybody starts with as well that question upvotes do still account for 10 here (has been reduced to 5 on major sites only). So it seems to be **exactly 4k** out of nowhere, which triggers the `API Evangelist` bonus association, albeit this one would have been rewarded on an either/or base regarding the `API Beta` bonus.

Comment: Rereading my own comment let me to the conclusion you might be up to something here: if one looks at the users activity/timeline it is noticeable that the `API Beta` badge **has been rewarded on Aug 8**, way out of line with all others, which have been awarded around the time the Public Beta started (May 20), of course. So maybe a recalculation of the users reputation on Aug 8 triggered a bug (possibly including a deleted post indeed) in the most definitely 'one off' code regarding this special *badge + bonus* mode not applied elsewhere usually?